# Getting description field from Active Directory in SQL Server 2005 (LDAP)

Tags: sql-server-2005, active-directory, ldap

The only field I cannot grab is the `description` field from our AD. The error is:

> *Cannot get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for
>   linked server "ADSI". Could not
>   convert the data value due to reasons
>   other than sign mismatch or overflow.*

Is there some datatype I can use to handle the object it is trying to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is the fact that AD can store multiple values in a single field (quite contrary to the very first normalization rule in relational databases).

Not sure what your query looks like - but could you possibly try to add a "[0]" indexer to the description attribute, by any chance??

Marc

Comment: unfortunatley no, i just re-wrote our AD query in a CLR Stored Proc and Function in .net to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem getting the `Description` field from AD while attempting to use `ADsDSOObject` and `ADO`.

you have to inter-ate through the values with a `For Each` or `Do until ... EOF` type of statement.

[Here is a good example](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Scripting/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/2006-12/msg00200.html)